# CSS responsive design for smartphone

Tags: html, css

I created a little page: [Link](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Startseite/)
Here is the code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
}

.text {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: white;
}

ul{
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i view this side with my laptop it looks normal (i use Mozilla). Now i opened the page with my smartphone and it looks like this.
[image: Picture]

At the picture the number 1 is perfect, but not the picture 2. The text field should be 70% of the screen. Maybe someone of you have an idea.

Comment: Thats because it isnt a responsive code. It is just a div with no fix width. If you want real responsive (or adaptive) code you will need `@media-query`-es and `viewport` meta tag. ;)

Comment: okay... i dont like media querys :D Then i have to read a bit :P Thanks

Comment: media query do this work for you :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @Skeptar, take a look at this insanely and amazing OCD mobile media query file :
http://annikalidne.com/code/the-insanely-ocd-mobile-media-queries-css-file

thanks to "Annika Lidne" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a viewport in `head`:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also, you can specify your mobile CSS inside a media query:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

See [Media queries for standard devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: Are there some definid `min-device-width : 375px)
max-device-width : 667px` for smartphones or tablets?

Comment: Yeha thanks. But what is portrait and landscape? is that the position of the smartphone? rotation?

Comment: Yes. You can specify the orientation in a media query as well

Answer (score 3):

Try using this meta tag in your HMTL head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For more info on this, take a look at this article on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: Thanks for thwer answer! :)

Comment: Don't worry about it! ;)